# How does one write a mathematical paper?

Tags: education, publishing

I am an undergraduate student of computer science. I do mathematics on the side. There are some ideas I think are worthy of publishing, and doing so would certainly be good for my academic credentials.

I contacted a professor about this issue and the paper I had prepared was not really written as a math paper. So I need to know how to actually write one. Please, write down all clues you think are noteworthy and link useful pages.

How long should a paper be? Is it a problem if it has just about $10$ pages?

I was told my introduction needs to be longer than it is. Why can I not just write "In this paper, I shall derive formulae for integrals of this form." and proceed further?

Comment: This seems an awfully broad question. Have you read any math papers? Undergraduate math books for math majors? What, specifically, makes your paper not suitable, according to the professor? What makes you think the result is significant enough to warrant a paper?

Comment: If you go here:  https://arxiv.org/archive/math and start clicking, you can find 1000's of examples of math papers.  Maybe click on the "number theory" link and poke around in there.

Comment: The hardest part is to come up with results or ideas that are sufficiently novel to be considered worthy of publication. You have to check carefully that the results are not already known, or that the results would not be considered trivial by someone who is an expert in that particular area. Another challenge is learning to write precisely, for example defining all terms precisely, meeting the standards of say a real analysis textbook.

Comment: I edited my answer a little because I realised you don't really mention journals or publication at all. And if indeed you aren't bothered about getting it into a journal, then maybe just write it up in a way that is correct and complete and make it available on your own website or ArXiv. If you do CS I'm sure you know how to literally write down math... maybe you don't need worry too much about fitting the exact conventions of 'pro' math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a tricky thing to get good answers to sites like this; a lot of the conventions you get from reading papers and writing other things that aren't 'papers'. Briefly on the specific questions:

- No, plenty of papers are only 10 pages.
- No, you don't need a long introduction.
- It *might* be appropriate to just start with exactly what the main result of the paper is in a no-nonsense way, but this takes some experience to get right because one is usually expected to contextualize the problem. If it's some isolated curiosity then it may not need much context, but if some bigger, deeper, or more well-known problem, it ought to have much more context to meet conventional expectations.

Comment: First:  read 20–30 papers in the subfield of interest.  (You'll have to cite prior work anyway, so read such papers.)